# How to count the values in this type of query?

Tags: sql-server

I HAVE 2 QUERY...HOW TO COMBINE THIS...

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(ID)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ID IN(2,3) GROUP BY ID
```

RESULT LIKE

```
2 5
3 9
```

I HAVE TO ADD 5+9

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(ID)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ID NOT IN(5)
GROUP BY ID
```

I want to combine this queries and get as one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you just want to get count of rows where id in {2,3}

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (2,3)
```